# Why is the import keyword useful?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript I can import another module\namespace like so:

```
namespace Shapes2 {
    import shapes = Shapes;

    var bar = new shapes.Bar();
}
```

However, I can just as easily refer to the namespace directly.

```
namespace Shapes3{
    var shapes = Shapes;

    var bar = new shapes.Bar();
}
```

Is `import` doing anything useful?

When would I want to type `import` rather than `var`?

Answer (score 5):

In that specific case, no it's not doing anything useful. [That syntax is for creating aliases](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces.md#aliases) for namespaces. Your example would be more useful in a situation like this:

```
namespace Shapes2 {
  import Rects = Shapes.Rectangles;

  var bar = new Rects.Red();
  // Instead of `var bar = new Shapes.Rectangles.Red()`
}
```

Basically, it's just a way of reducing the amount of typing you do. In a way, it's a substitution for [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx) in C#. But how does this differ from `var`?

> This is similar to using `var`, but also works on the type and namespace meanings of the imported symbol. Importantly, for values, `import` is a distinct reference from the original symbol, so changes to an aliased `var` will not be reflected in the original variable.

[source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces.md#aliases)

A good example of this can be found [in the spec:](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#103-import-alias-declarations)

```
namespace A {  
    export interface X { s: string }  
}

namespace B {  
    var A = 1;  
    import Y = A;  
}
```

> 'Y' is a local alias for the non-instantiated namespace 'A'. If the declaration of 'A' is changed such that 'A' becomes an instantiated namespace, for example by including a variable declaration in 'A', the import statement in 'B' above would be an error because the expression 'A' doesn't reference the namespace instance of namespace 'A'.
>
> When an import statement includes an export modifier, all meanings of the local alias are exported.

Comment: But I can replace the `import` with `var` and everything works just the same.

Comment: In your example, I could just use `var` instead and save myself three key presses.  I'm still not getting why it was invented.

Comment: @BanksySan As my edit points out, using `import` means you get a distinct reference. Meaning, any changes made to it won't change the original aliased value.

Comment: @BanksySan The import allows you to shorten commonly used namespaces. It's syntactical sugar, that's all. Simply to shorten namespaces from lengthy ones to shorter, more manageable ones.

Comment: @ManoDestra but so does `var`...  If I replace the `import` keyword with `var` it's all exactly the same.  Isn't it?

Comment: @BanksySan Again, in your exact situation it isn't helpful other than being a good indicator of intent. If all you're doing is referencing a namespace and nothing more then there's no reason to use `import`. `import` is useful for more advanced use cases as indicated above.

Comment: @BanksySan No, not really. If you use var, for multiple objects within that namespace, then you'll be writing those lengthy namespaces over and over with EVERY var declaration. If you're only referring to a single object in the namespace, then it's less likely to be useful. You COULD then just use var, but if you're going to have to refer to a particular lengthy namespace repeatedly for numerous objects, then import is the way to go. Not very useful in YOUR use case, but it is useful in more complex use cases.

Comment: @ManoDestra I'm sure you're right and I'm just not seeing it yet.  The penny will drop further down the road.

Comment: `var x1 = new path.to.namespace.Object1(); var x2 = path.tonamespace.Object2(); var x3 = new path.to.namespace.Object3();` If you include an import for path.to.namespace at the top, then the above can be abbreviated with ease to avoid the multiple references to the same lengthy namespace. Make sense? E.g. `var x1 = new abbrev.Object1(); var x2 = new abbrev.Object2(); var x3 = new abbrev.Object3();`

Comment: @ManoDestra I think they're saying they have the option of doing `var o = path.to.namespace; var x1 = new o.Object1()`.

Comment: @ManoDestra Wouldn't `var namespace = path.to.namespace` then `var x1 = new namespace.Object1()` work too?

Comment: @MikeC Yeah, I see what you mean. You could, yes, but the import is arguably cleaner syntax. You're then using var to do two functionally different things, where the import can differentiate from the normal function of var.

Answer (score 0):

From the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

> Another way that you can simplify working with of namespaces is to use import q = x.y.z **to create shorter names for commonly-used objects**. Not to be confused with the import x = require("name") syntax used to load modules, **this syntax simply creates an alias for the specified symbol**. You can use these sorts of imports (commonly referred to as aliases) for any kind of identifier, including objects created from module imports.